# Automated Shutdown on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, shutdown, windows-task-scheduler

I want my PC to shutdown automatically after 15 minutes of idle time, however i want the notice to have an abort button on it. And after clicking on it, the task will wait for the next time my PC will be idled. But if the abort button was not clicked, the computer will continue to shutdown after 5 minutes. so all in all my PC got 20 minutes to forcefully shut itself down.

i know how to use task scheduler but i don't know much about the script part on it. Sorry i'm not that very good on computers and I thank you in advance for helping me.

NOTE: What i want is to abort the shutdown for the mean time and not to abort the whole task, so the PC will continue to ask the user every time the system will be in idle and not when the user is still moving the mouse and pressing keys on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If the user interacts; that would de-facto cancel the idle state; so all you should need to do is give a message that the system will be shutdown soon due to being idle.

If you had an "abort" or "cancel" button, you wouldn't actually have to code it to "do" anything; since the user clicking it (or even moving the mouse towards it) would be an interaction to cancel the idle state.

If you still want more fine-grained control over how you're using those idle states though; this document is a good reference: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: the only option is "close" and when ever the task started there is no stopping it., even if i use the computer after the shutdown notice (canceling the idle state) it will still shut itself down after 5 minutes.

Comment: In that case; I think you might need to use the IIdleSettings::StopOnIdleEnd property here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380722(v=vs.85).aspx

"A Boolean value that indicates that the Task Scheduler will terminate the task if the idle condition ends before the task is completed. The idle condition ends when the computer is no longer idle."

If that's still not quite what you're looking for, a sample showing what you've got working so far might make it a bit clearer.

Comment: yes, that's what I've been looking for., the problem now is how am i be able to use it?